# Flutter - How to download video and save them to internal storage?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a project in flutter and I need to implement video downloading from server feature .I'm considering using Dio library and saving the downloaded video to `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` but I haven't find an example of what I want to achieve , I tried some examples and tried to modify them but it just did not work .
Anyone has an idea on how to manage that ? Thanks .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below

code snippet

```
Future<void> downloadFile() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();

    try {
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      print("path ${dir.path}");
      await dio.download(imgUrl, "${dir.path}/demo.mp4",
          onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {
        print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");

        setState(() {
          downloading = true;
          progressString = ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      downloading = false;
      progressString = "Completed";
    });
    print("Download completed");
  }
```

working demo

[image]

output

```
I/flutter (18244): path /data/user/0/yourdoamin.yourproject/app_flutter
I/flutter (18244): Rec: 2124 , Total: 2429896
I/flutter (18244): Rec: 4883 , Total: 2429896
...
I/flutter (18244): Rec: 2429896 , Total: 2429896
I/flutter (18244): Download completed
```

full code

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final imgUrl = "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4";
  bool downloading = false;
  var progressString = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    downloadFile();
  }

  Future<void> downloadFile() async {
    Dio dio = Dio();

    try {
      var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      print("path ${dir.path}");
      await dio.download(imgUrl, "${dir.path}/demo.mp4",
          onReceiveProgress: (rec, total) {
        print("Rec: $rec , Total: $total");

        setState(() {
          downloading = true;
          progressString = ((rec / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    setState(() {
      downloading = false;
      progressString = "Completed";
    });
    print("Download completed");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("AppBar"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: downloading
            ? Container(
                height: 120.0,
                width: 200.0,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Downloading File: $progressString",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Text("No Data"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I spend a lot of time finding that directory but not able to find it. I'm downloading videos.

Comment: In order to download file to the downloads folder in android you have to request the permission for storage which is specified first in the android manifest and then write to /storage/emulated/0/Download. The methods provided by path provider only provide locations to the apps local directory.

Comment: @chunhunghan what will happen when download fails completing for internet connection and how can we find that file to play later ?

Comment: if I change the link to a youtube video it doesn't work, any advice>

Comment: will the video downloaded be only in the app storage  ?